# calculate percentage of aggregated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using the following result set:

```
|       DATE | BUSINESS |   COLLEAGUE |   POSITION | HOURS | STANDARDHOURS | COUNTER | OVER16 | OVER32 | OVER48 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-01-01 |        a |   bob jones |    analyst |   168 |           168 |       1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| 2013-01-01 |        a | cindy jones |  assistant |   184 |           168 |       1 |      1 |      0 |      0 |
| 2013-01-01 |        b |  tim harris | programmer |   200 |           168 |       1 |      1 |      1 |      0 |
| 2013-01-01 |        b |   tom white |    manager |   216 |           168 |       1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
| 2013-02-01 |        a |   bob jones |    analyst |   176 |           176 |       1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| 2013-02-01 |        a | cindy jones |  assistant |   176 |           176 |       1 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| 2013-02-01 |        b |  tim harris | programmer |   200 |           176 |       1 |      1 |      0 |      0 |
| 2013-02-01 |        b |   tom white |    manager |   216 |           176 |       1 |      1 |      1 |      0 |
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT c.date, 
       c.business, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(c.over16) > 0 THEN ( Sum(c.over16) / Sum(c.counter) ) * 100 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS percOver16, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(c.over32) > 0 THEN ( Sum(c.over32) / Sum(c.counter) ) * 100 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS percOver32, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(c.over48) > 0 THEN ( Sum(c.over48) / Sum(c.counter) ) * 100 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS percOver48 
FROM   (SELECT a.date, 
               a.business, 
               a.colleague, 
               a.position, 
               a.hours, 
               b.standardhours, 
               1   AS counter, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN a.hours >= b.standardhours + 16 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END AS over16, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN a.hours >= b.standardhours + 32 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END AS over32, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN a.hours >= b.standardhours + 48 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END AS over48 
        FROM   colleaguetime a 
               JOIN businesshours b 
                 ON b.date = a.date) c 
GROUP  BY c.date, 
          c.business
```

I get:

```
|       DATE | BUSINESS | PERCOVER16 | PERCOVER32 | PERCOVER48 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-01-01 |        a |          0 |          0 |          0 |
| 2013-01-01 |        b |        100 |        100 |          0 |
| 2013-02-01 |        a |          0 |          0 |          0 |
| 2013-02-01 |        b |        100 |          0 |          0 |
```

The desired result is:

```
|       DATE | BUSINESS | PERCOVER16 | PERCOVER32 | PERCOVER48 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-01-01 |        a |         50 |          0 |          0 |
| 2013-01-01 |        b |        100 |        100 |         50 |
| 2013-02-01 |        a |          0 |          0 |          0 |
| 2013-02-01 |        b |        100 |         50 |          0 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d721/1)

Is there an easier way to do this using a CTE?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Multiple by 100 first, *then* divide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem that you are having is the integer divide problem.  You want to convert the values to a decimal or floating point format before doing the division.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT c.date, 
       c.business, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(c.over16) > 0 THEN ( Sum(c.over16*1.0) / Sum(c.counter) ) * 100 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS percOver16, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(c.over32) > 0 THEN ( Sum(c.over32*1.0) / Sum(c.counter) ) * 100 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS percOver32, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(c.over48) > 0 THEN ( Sum(c.over48*1.0) / Sum(c.counter) ) * 100 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS percOver48
```

EDIT:

The simplest alternative is to change the definition of counter in the subquery:

```
1.0 as counter,   -- This has a decimal point so it can be used for division
```

This will define it as a non-integer, numeric data type.

As a general rule for production code, I like to have these conversions where the division is happening, to prevent unexpected errors.  Somewhere down the road, you or someone else could look at a line like `1.0 as counter` and think "That's stupid.  `Counter` should be an integer."  You or he or she then changes it, and stuff breaks.  Or someone sees the `sum(c.counter)` and thinks "That's stupid.  It could just do `count(*)` or `count(c.counter)`.

On the other hand, for ad-hoc code, I'd probably just make the counter `1.0`.

Comment: Thanks, do you want to add the alternative which is changing `1 as counter` to `1.0 as counter`?

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this by using the following in your subquery:

```
SELECT a.date, a.business, a.colleague, a.position, a.hours, b.standardHours,
    1 AS counter,
    CASE WHEN a.hours >= b.standardHours + 16
      THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END AS over16,
    CASE WHEN a.hours >= b.standardHours + 32
      THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END AS over32,
    CASE WHEN a.hours >= b.standardHours + 48
      THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END AS over48
FROM colleagueTime a
JOIN businessHours b ON b.date = a.date;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d721/10)

Instead of using `1` and `0`, change the values to `1.0` so they are decimals instead of integers.

Or as Gordon pointed out, you can use 1.0 as the counter value:

```
SELECT a.date, a.business, a.colleague, a.position, a.hours, b.standardHours,
    1.0 AS counter,
    CASE WHEN a.hours >= b.standardHours + 16
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS over16,
    CASE WHEN a.hours >= b.standardHours + 32
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS over32,
    CASE WHEN a.hours >= b.standardHours + 48
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS over48
FROM colleagueTime a
JOIN businessHours b ON b.date = a.date;
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
Sum(c.over16) / Sum(c.counter)
```

to:

```
cast(SUM(c.over16) as float) / cast(SUM(c.counter) as float)
```

(and all other ones as well.)

Dividing whole numbers results in whole numbers. You need to cast to float first.